# IntelliJ fails to launch AIR 3.9 ADL

Tags: actionscript-3, air, intellij-idea

I've asked the same question on the JetBrains forums (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/450521?tstart=0), but figured I'd ask here as well in order to cover my bases:

I just upgraded (well, I tried this a couple weeks ago too, but was too busy then to try to deal with this problem) to AIR 3.9 from 3.8. Under 3.8, my build/launch configurations all worked just fine. Now in 3.9, I get the "initial content not found" error from ADL. The mysterious thing is that if I immediately copy the adl command from the IntelliJ run box to the command line, it works just fine. This would be OK as a stopgap, except for one thing: I can't debug using this workaround. As far as I can tell, this is new with 3.9. I've used IntelliJ 12 with several versions of AIR 3.8 with no problem.

Is this just straight up a bug that needs to get fixed by IntelliJ? I don't mind submitting a bug report if that's the case, I'm just not sure yet this isn't something I can't fix locally.

Comment: I believe I saw a post on the Adobe forums saying this was a bug on JetBrains' end (there was an in-progress ticket in their bug tracker, if I recall correctly). Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Any chance you have a link to that post handy? I did some googling for this problem before posting questions here and on IntelliJ's forum, and found nothing.

Comment: Here. It was on the Starling Forums, not the Adobe forums. http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/air-sdk-39-released And the ticket. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114714

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a different problem from what I'm experiencing. I've added a separate bug report on the jetbrains tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest AIR sdk (3.9.1200) made the problem go away. http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html

Comment: Was just coming back to let you know this. Got an email from a friend about two hours ago that let me know.